# Create and use translation resources in an HTML5 web application

Tags: html, web, translation

I'm creating a rich web application using HTML5/JQuery and Java EE and I need to make it possible for this application to be displayed in English as well as in French. I'm new with HTML5 so I don't know if it's possible to do it easily and, if so, how should I do it ?

I have very good notions in Flex and, with this technology, it's really easy to do : you just need to store a "dictionary" in 2 different files.
For example :

```
file english:

title = Welcome to my app !

file French :

title = Bienvenu dans mon appli !
```

and then call {resourceManager.getString('file','title')} each time you need a term to be translated.

Is there any similar way to do it in HTML ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar with javascript.
There are many ways to do this, I'll just throw in the way I'd do it.

I'd store the translations in some plain javascript files.

lang_english.js

```
var language = 
{
  "title" : "Welcome to my app"
}
```

lang_french.js

```
var language = 
{
  "title" : "Bienvenu dans mon appli !"
}
```

You can load one of these files in the html head:

```
<script src="lang_english.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then in your app you can create a resourceManager object:

```
resourceManager = {}
resourceManager.getString = function(str)
{
  return language[str];
}
```

and then call:

```
var title = resourceManager.getString('title')
```

**Edit**:

For dynamic loading, you can store them in `.json` files and use `jquery` to dynamically load them based on the user language selection:

```
var language = {};

$.get('lang_french.json', function(data) {
    language = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

The `lang_french.json` file would look like this:

```
{
  "title" : "Bienvenu dans mon appli !"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I still have a question about this solution. If you have to specify the right file in the HTML head, I guess it means you have to duplicate your html files to provide one in French and one in English? Is it possible to load the right file or the right resource dynamically depending on the user's language choice? Thanks again.

Comment: ah, yes, please see my updated answer. You can use an ajax call with jquery to retrieve some `json` dinamically.